# Understand JMeter technicalities for comparing distributed vs independent JMeter engines

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I'd few ques on technical details of JMeter mostly pertaining to distributed setup vs independent JMeter engines (since JMeter controller can become a bottleneck in case of several JMeter load generators). Would be great if anybody can help with the understanding here -

- How is JMeter distributed setup orchestrated by JMeter controller (i.e. called master or client)? Can we use the same logic to synchronize test among independent JMeter engines (independent mode)?
- Is there a way to pool connections across vUsers?
- Function of ASYNC_QUEUE in backend listener and it's expected side-effects in independent mode (mentioned above), what happens when queue is full?
- Does/Is there a way for JMeter to execute javascript/act as headless browser?
- How does DNS resolution happen for JMeter? Does it resolve for each vuser?

Answer (score 1):

Your "question" looks like a compilation of interview questions rather than something connected with your single current concern and I don't think it's a proper place/way to ask it, I believe it should be: one post - one question.

Whatever

1. `How is JMeter distributed setup orchestrated by JMeter controller` - JMeter master sends .jmx script to slaves and collects results from them. Theoretically you can implement your own mechanism for delivering the test plan and eventual dependencies to the individual JMeter engines and running the test at the same time. Then you will need to collect the [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) from the engines and combine it into a single one.
2. `Is there a way to pool connections across vUsers?` - JMeter does it [internally](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPHC4Impl.java#L1087)
3. When the queue is full no more new sample results will be taken for processing by the backend listener so the results won't be "realtime" anymore, you will see the new results as free slots will be appearing in the queue
4. For JMeter per-se - no, AJAX calls can be simulated using [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller), for client-side performance testing, JavaScript execution profiling and rendering speed measurement you will need to use a read browser, no matter normal or headless, there is [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin providing JMeter integration with Selenium
5. DNS resolution is dependent on underlying OS and/or JVM DNS resolution implementation, there is [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/) which enables overriding hosts entries and using custom DNS resolver so each thread looks up the IP address on its own